# Using PHP to find unlinked columns in two different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have two tables, one called 'questions' and one called 'tests'. Each row in 'questions' has the columns 'id','test' and several other columns not relevant to this question. The 'tests' table has the columns 'id','name' and several others not relevant.

Basically, on my website, every time someone creates a test, a new row is created in 'tests' and its given an 'id'. From there, every question the user makes, creates a new row in the 'questions' table, each question is given an 'id' as well as 'test' column having the same number as the 'id' from the 'tests' table to which it belongs.

Yesterday we mistakenly deleted several rows from the 'tests' table, however all the questions are still in the 'questions' table, meaning we just need to find which rows in the 'questions' table have a 'test' value that isn't linked to any 'id' in the 'tests' table, so this is the .php script we came up with:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'hidden',  'hidden') or die ('Error connecting');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('hidden', $conn);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $test = $row['test'];
    $questionID = $row['id'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tests where id = $test";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
    if ($num_rows == 0) {
        echo "Unlinked question: $questionID (test $test) <br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

However, it doesn't echo any "Unlinked question.. " which would help us identify which tests we have lost and need to recreate, giving them the correct 'id' to link to the 'questions' table 'test' column. Is there another way to fix this problem? And yes, we have do backup the tables, but unfortunately we only do it every other week, and most of the deleted tests were recent.

Update:

```
$sql = "
SELECT q.id AS QuestionID
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN tests t
ON  (q.test = t.id)
WHERE q.test IS NOT NULL AND t.id IS NULL";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$questionID = $row['QuestionID'];
$testID = $row['test'];
echo $row;
echo "The question with the id: $questionID is not linked to the test: $testID";
}

?>
```

Comment: What are you using `$row2` for?

Comment: I was trying something else, should have removed that sorry

Comment: You should be using `or die(mysql_error())` on all of your mysql functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you do this in a single SQL statement??

```
SELECT
    q.id AS QuestionID,
    CASE WHEN q.test IS NOT NULL AND t.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UnlinkedQuestion
FROM
    questions q
LEFT JOIN
    tests t
    ON  (q.test = t.id)
```

OR, if you only want to return unlinked question id, simply move the logic into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    q.id AS QuestionID
FROM
    questions q
LEFT JOIN
    tests t
    ON  (q.test = t.id)
WHERE
    q.test IS NOT NULL AND
    t.id IS NULL
```

**NOTE:**

I would highly recommend that you add foreign key constraints to your *question* table on the test id, so that you can prevent the same error with accidentally deleting records from your *test* table.

Comment: I'm pretty new to php, well programming in general (started about a month ago), would love an explanation to your answer, or have you used the correct variables and I can just copy the exact code?

Comment: You may be able to copy it - I don't know your table columns because you are using '*' in your select statement, so you may need to tweak this a little.

Basically, you are just joining the two tables on that test id. If the question table has a test id, but doesn't match with the test table, that indicates your unlinked question

Comment: I've updated the question with the code you gave, but I'm quite sure what to define the variable as that I need to echo? Also, we used to have foreign key restrains but a lot of the tests uploaded by users had questions missing

Comment: does `FROM questions q` make `q` a reference to `questions`?

Comment: @Nile yea, 'q' is simply the alias

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - First, does the code in your update work for you? Is it echo'ing the question ids?

Comment: Can I ask what the 'AS' part does? Does it create a new variable called 'QuestionID' in this case? And no it's not echoing anything

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - 'AS' simply indicates that you are providing an alias for the column (instead of 'id' it will return as 'QuestionID'.

I don't know what $unlinkedQuestion has in it, but that is probably your issue. Why can't you do this in your while loop: `echo $row;`

Comment: That makes more sense, I've added the echo $row; as well as an echo that should make it more clear what I expect from the script, added the whole code to the Update part of my question, however it's not echoing anything (i've checked for errors - nothing, the script is running) @nile

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - Does the query return anything? Are there even any records that match that logic in the query? If you can, you should try to execute the query inside of a MySQL client like [http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/)

Comment: It doesn't return anything. Well I assume the logic is searching for questions that have a value in q.test which doesn't match any value in t.id? If so, then yes, there should be hundreds of records - I've manually found many questions myself, but I need this to work in order to not spend the next few days doing this, I'll have a look at some cheaper mysql clients, however I feel they may take some time to learn

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - Devart has a free/express version, which is all you need. Based on your description of the tables, the query should give you exactly what you are looking for. You should take an example of a question you **know** has a test value, but no corresponding test and filter the query to show you what it returns -- *troubleshoot*

Comment: The new code you've posted in your answer works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Nile - it should, it's very simple. :)

Comment: It's working now! Not sure why I had to do the troubleshoot thing first then return it back to the code above but it works. Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - Glad to hear! And, again, I would recommend looking into foreign constraints as to help prevent this same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of your `mysql_*` functions so it's easier to identify any issues.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I see, I'll check out the PDO tutorial once I sort this issue out, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: It didn't, I echoed the $num_rows before the if clause, and checked the page, there were only '1' on the page, meaning it's only querying the linked questions, if you see what I mean?

Comment: I dont understand... can you put the `or die(mysql_error())` on all of your mysql functions so I can further assist you?

Comment: That would look something like: `$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn) or die(mysql_error());` on all of your `mysql_*` functions

Comment: @Nile - I think he is looking for the questions in the question table where there is a value in the column 'test', which should match with the 'id' column in test, but does not because he had accidentally deleted some records in the test table.

Comment: @Nick - I understand what he's trying to do, I don't understand what he was trying to say in that comment ^.

Comment: @Nile - I understand; yes, I don't think his response relates to your answer.

Comment: Thats correct, basically I need the script to echo the 'id' of each question followed by the value of the 'test' column so I know what to put in the 'id' column on the 'tests' table when I recreate the rows. @Nile,I added the or die(mysql_error()); but the script is functioning, so there is nothing in the error_log

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - have you added the `or die(mysql_error())` to your original code also?

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - If you don't add that to the script as Nile suggests, you are missing out on some potentially very helpful information about your problem.

Comment: Yes I've added the or die to my original, but there is nothing in the error_log, unless I'm supposed to find an error somewhere else?

Comment: I can't give reputations, says I need to have a reputation of 15 myself, but I ticked it if that helps :)